# Trying to get a basic highcharts cylinder chart working on streamlit

Tags: python, highcharts, streamlit

I've been able to get a highcharts  waterfallchart and an area chart working on streamlit, but the cylinder chart is not displaying anything. Would love it if someone could take a look at my code....

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit_highcharts as hct

chart_week_day={
    "chart": {
        "type": "cylinder",
        "options3d": {
            "enabled": True,
            "alpha": 8,
            "beta": 15,
            "depth": 50,
            "viewDistance": 150
        }
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Return by Weekday"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"],
        "title": {
            "text": ''
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "margin": 40,
            "text": '$'
        }
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "depth": 300,
            "colorByPoint": False,
            "negativeColor": 'pink'
        }
    },
    "series": [{
        "data": [200,300,400,500,600],
        "name": '$',
        "showInLegend": False
    }]
}

hct.streamlit_highcharts(chart_week_day,500,key="week_day")
```

Comment: Where do you get streamlit_highcharts?

Comment: Hi, I found that, so I just went through and did what he said... https://github.com/aalteirac/streamlit_highcharts

Comment: The error message is `missingModuleFor: cylinder`. Probably cylinder is not properly implemented / not implemented in streamlit_highcharts. It is better to raise an issue in that repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Series.data` expects numbers, whereas`xAxis.categories` should be strings. Therefore, you need to only swap categories and data values.

**JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qx3pzn1f/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.cylinder.data
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

As @ferdy mentioned, don't forget to include the necessary modules:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/cylinder.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I did have that wrong, in the question sorry to waste your time with that. You are right...I think Ferdy is on the money there, maybe hasn't been implemented